# Unable to Scan bar code from large distance?

Tags: android

I have to scan bar code form hording that placed on 70 to 80 ft above from my head.I used bar code scanner API but I am unable to scan bar code from the hording.There is any way that i can scan bar code from hording?

Comment: When you say "not working@, what do you mean, exactly?  My guess is that the distance is too great for the camera to pick up the barcode correctly.  You can try zooming the camera to the max before attempting to read the image, but I'm still not sure you'll succeed.

Comment: Dear there is no way to zoom camera in bar code scanner API.